# Error: listen EADDRINUSE when trying to run an Express.js application?

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

When I try to run my application an Express.js server, the first time with a new port works fine, but then when I try to run it again on that port, I get the "Error: listen EADDRINUSE" error.

I already tried killing all the possible node/gulp processes, also, checked netstat and I do not see port 8080 being used by anything.

What could be the culprit?

Comment: Pretty sure something's using that port. Node by default doesn't use 8080, either, although you don't actually provide any actionable info.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if the node process is still running your app when you go to run it again. Express will try to bind to the same port but it's already being use by the last node instance you created.

Kill all node processes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this post is very old. But right now I saw something.

When I was in the same situation as you are in, I opened the console in my browser and I can see some errors. When I solved those errors, everything works fine.